# Unable to call Javascript method from .swf which is loaded in the HTML page in Android WebView- Throws: security error: error #2060

Tags: javascript, android, actionscript-3, flash, webview

I've created a Android App where I've some .swf files inside my asset folder. I'm loading these files in a WebView. For that I've created a HTML page "`myHTML.html`" which loads the .swf file.
Here is my HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function diplayJavaMsg(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }

        function functionCalledFromSWF(Score) {
            alert(Score);
            JsHandler.callToJavaFunction(Score);
        }
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Sush19/Games/level/level.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="samedomain" />
        <param name="base" value="Sush19/Games/level" />
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my `Java class`

```
public class MainAct extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private WebView webView;
    private Button btn;
    private JsHandler _jsHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        loadGame(webView);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public void loadGame(WebView webViewID) {
        webViewID.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewID.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
        webViewID.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webViewID.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webViewID.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 8);
        webViewID.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webViewID.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webViewID.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webViewID.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        webViewID.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webViewID.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webViewID.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webViewID.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webViewID.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        String url = "file:///android_asset/myHTML.html";
        webViewID.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

JS Bridge Class

```
public class JsHandler {
    Activity activity;
    String TAG = "JsHandler";
    WebView webView;


    public JsHandler(Activity _contxt,WebView _webView) {
        activity = _contxt;
        webView = _webView;
    }

    /**
     * This function handles call from JS
     */
    public void callToJavaFunction(String Score) {

    }

    /**
     * This function handles call from Android-Java
     */
    public void javaFnCall(String jsString) {

        final String webUrl = "javascript:diplayJavaMsg('"+jsString+"')";
        // Add this to avoid android.view.windowmanager$badtokenexception unable to add window
        if(!activity.isFinishing()) 
            // loadurl on UI main thread
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.loadUrl(webUrl); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Code inside .swf which calls Javascript method:
Actionscript method:

```
public var environment:String="";
environment=ExternalInterface.call("functionCalledFromSWF");
```

I'm unable to call Javascript method from Actionscript in Android Webview. The .swf file plays fine in the WebView.

Comment: Hm, I think if you want to use Flash in Android, you should use AIR instead of regular Flash Player. I'm almost 100% sure you won't be able to run JavaScript from that page, just because it's a regular security breach. Would love to know if you make it :)

Comment: thanks for your respond @Andrey Popov, Ya I've done this using AIR, but this time I'm trying to play .swf file in Android WebView using HTML page and it works fine, the only problem I'm facing is; not able to call `JavaScript` from .swf and vice versa. I just want to get some parameters from .swf to my Activity. Let me try and let see if anyone have got any solution for it.